# Error https on backend configuration (Haproxy)

Tags: frontend, backend, haproxy, haproxy-ingress, custom-backend

Sorry guys for my bad English. Please kindly help me solve the following code below:

```
frontend server
  bind *:50095 ssl crt /part_to_certificate ciphers ALL:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXPORT:!SSLv2
  redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
  reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
  http-request redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
  http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
  mode http
  log global
  option httplog
  timeout client 120s
  maxconn 1000
  acl host_webess hdr(host) -i testing007.com.kh
  acl host_webess hdr(host) -i 10.0.1.10
  default_backend bk_server

backend bk_server
  balance roundrobin
  stick-table type ip size 200k expire 30m
  mode http
  option httpclose
  cookie JSESSIONID prefix indirect nocache
  log global
  cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache
  default-server inter 3s rise 2 fall 3
  timeout server 120s
  timeout queue 120s
  server test1 10.0.0.1:8080 cookie test1 weight 1 maxconn 380000 check inter 20000 rise 2 fall 5
  server test2 10.0.0.2:8080 cookie test2 weight 1 maxconn 380000 check inter 20000 rise 2 fall 5
```

I using 10.0.1.10 ip address with port 50095 for access to web interface browser, then I try to input with the wrong username and password. The result I got back is nothing.

By the way I want, when I try to input wrong username and password it will respond back like (Invalid username or Password) in this case I use https.

Moreover if I disable ssl and try to access with http it work find. everyone could you correct me.

Thank in advance

I try by researching on the internet but nothing got one.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcVHq.png)